# Share / repin button on pinterest

Tags: android, button, android-widget

developing an app, and I was wondering if someone on here could give me some general information about what this thing from the pinterest app on both android and ios is called and where i can find out more information about how to create a more basic one etc... it is where you press down and hold on a picture and 3 buttons come up in a fan sort of pattern. here is a pic[image]

thanks a bunch! Any info to start learning would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called an 'ArcMenu' and one Android implementation can be found here:

```
https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu
```

Credit to 'Capricorn' for the GitHub library

Comment: is there a way to do this without lib? by detecting press event and generating views on that coordinates?